# VUEJS data.map is not a function

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using VueJS and got an error message that I didnt have before. The incidents var is an array, so it should work I would assume?

In my HTML file I included:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.2.0/vue-resource.js"></script>
```

When I log the output of response.data I see an array:

[image]

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.data.map is not a function
>       at Vue$3. (main.js:17)

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        responders: [],
        incidents: []
    },

    mounted: function () {
        this.getIncidents();
    },

    methods: {
        getIncidents: function() {
            console.log('getIncidents');
            var app = this;
            this.$http.get('/api/v1/incidents').then(function(response) {
                // set data on vm
                var incidentsReceived = response.data.map(function (incident) {
                    return incident
                });
                Vue.set(app, 'incidents', incidentsReceived);
            });
        }
})
```

Comment: What does `console.log(response.data)` give you? My initial thought would be that it isn't an array.

Comment: Hi Ross, I added the pic of the console output when I print response.data

Comment: Would you also be able to show what you have for your Route/Controller method?

Comment: probably off topic, but its not a good idea to have `var app = ...` twice

Comment: As @nozzleman said it is going to be a good idea to change `var app = this` to something like `var self = this` and then change all the references within that method.

Comment: @sesc360 Can you show your controller method `/api/v1/incidents`??

Answer (score 3):

You can not map over the response. Try setting the response data to your data so do

```
this.$http.get('/api/v1/incidents').then((response) => {
                // set data in your data object
                this.incidents = response.data
                // Now you can map over the incidents and return 
                return this.incidents.map(incident => return)
            });
```